# ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lstdc++

Tags: compiling, c++, clang

CMake is complaining that I don't have a working c++ compiled because of the error:

```
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lstdc++
```

I've narrowed it down the following:

- Given the program `int main(){return 0;}`
- And the commands

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT prog.o -MF prog.d -o prog.o -c prog.cpp
/usr/bin/clang++ -fuse-ld=lld prog.o -o prog
```

The second command is failing with the given error. How can I fix my Ubuntu C++ installation to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with your C++ environment configuration, you could try to resolve your linker, update your linker and compiler and check for their versions. If this does not work you could update your alternative linker `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ld ld /usr/bin/ld.lld 100` 
This command will set ld to use ld.lld as the default linker. Try recompiling after this. It should probably help.